# Как накатить SVN patch на GIT'овый репозиторий?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Разработка переехала из Subversion в git. Но некоторые изменения не были залиты в svn (не прошли кодревью). Сейчас прошли, но заливать код уже нужно не в SVN, а в GIT.

Отсюда вопрос: как применить SVN PATCH файл к GIT'овому репозиторию?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы изначально делали миграцию из SVN в GIT через git-svn, и репозиторий SVN еще жив - то достаточно просто забрать последние изменения из SVN, слить их и запушить.

Если же миграция делалась по-другому, то можно просто удалить все в рабочей копии, скопировать туда файлы из SVN и закоммитить изменения.

Если репозитория SVN уже нет - можно попробовать создать новый репозиторий, накатить на него этот патч, после чего перенести изменения в гит как в прошлом пункте.

Comment: Т.е. утилит прямого наката SVN патчей на GIT Нет?